# How to require a jar file in Clojure REPL?

Tags: java, clojure

It's easy to `require` a package from clojure:

```
user=> (require 'clojure.core)
nil
```

But how can I require a `.jar` file inside Clojure?

(I'm trying to learn `lein`. Leiningen is useful to big projects rather than small scripts. So I want to figure out that what's the best method to use a `jar` package in my Clojure scripts and in REPL.)

Comment: You should probably use leinginen to set up your classpath and dependencies. That should take care of 99% of the issues and annoyances. See https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen

Answer (score 4):

Although it's possible to add a jar to an application at runtime with the help of the [Pomegranate](https://github.com/cemerick/pomegranate) library, it's highly discouraged as:

1. It hides the dependency from the outside, and end users won't know they need it to run the code.
2. The jar itself can depend on other jar files (and hence put strain on end users to figure it out)

I think I'm repeating the other respondents, but thought I'd add the points to validate their advices.

As a matter of fact, lein2 uses pomegranate under the covers, just for the purpose of not having to restart REPL after a dependency is needed. It's only for development purposes.

Comment: do I have to do something special to get lein2 to notice the new dependencies?

Comment: It depends on how you define _"something special"_ :) You should find the dependency in [clojars](https://clojars.org/) or [maven repo](http://search.maven.org/#browse) and add it to **project.clj**. The very first example at [leiningen.org](http://leiningen.org/) shows **:dependencies** section for your reference.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can.  The REPL has to be started with the JAR on the classpath.

Comment: How to start Clojure REPL with JAR then? Since I googled, I only find `java` command has this option. Is there any replacement in Clojure?

Comment: You add the jar as a dependency in the project.clj

Comment: So, you mean lein is the only solution.

Comment: @Alex Baranosky: you can dynamically add jars at runtime from the REPL just like you can dynamically add jars to a running Java program at runtime.  However this is probably more trouble than it's worth: I'd recommend using Leiningen instead.  But still... this can  be done: I've reused (from Clojure) bootstrapping code from a Java project that does resolve dependencies at runtime by dynamically adding jars to the classpath and it worked fine from the REPL : )

Comment: lein is not the only solution. However, it's the easiest for Clojure.

Answer (score 2):

So, checking `man clojure` for my REPL on Ubuntu 14.04 got me to `-cp` option (which is short for `-classpath`):

```
clojure -cp ./path/to/package.jar
user=> (require `clojure.package)
```

---

In fact, for reference I would like to share an example of using a `jar` library. Since it might be useful for somebody who is not familiar with Java (and all the machinery), but wants to use this nice lisp for scripting/short-nice-small programs and therefore has no need for leiningen.

Example is: you want to parse some files with CSV content and use it somehow.

- Files on file system are acessed with standard `clojure.java.io`,
- the CSV content is parsed with external [package `data.csv`](https://github.com/clojure/data.csv)

Download `data.csv.jar` following [the link from the README](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|g%3A"org.clojure"%20AND%20a%3A"data.csv"): http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/clojure/data.csv/0.1.4/data.csv-0.1.4.jar

Put it in your current working directory and open REPL adding the path to `classpath`:

```
clojure -cp ./data.csv-0.1.4.jar
Clojure 1.4.0
user=> ; now you have it
user=> (require '[clojure.data.csv :as csv])
nil
user=>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Pomegranate](https://github.com/cemerick/pomegranate) library.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this [solution](http://blog.japila.pl/2011/01/dynamically-redefining-classpath-in-clojure-repl/).

In repl:

```
user=>(def cl (-> (Thread/currentThread) (.getContextClassLoader)))
;; need load dependicies before, using the same method
user=>(-> cl (.addURL (java.net.URL. "file:///c:/Users/dev/m2/repository/cheshire/cheshire/5.3.1/cheshire-5.3.1.jar")))
user=>(require '[cheshire.core :as json])
```